# Skip files when building application using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have an Angular application built directly by Webpack because when we first started developing it, Angular CLI did not support everything we needed. As it has become quite mature by now, we are trying to switch to Angular CLI in order to make project maintenance a little bit easier.

The repository with our application is both an NPM project and a Maven project since it is deployed on WildFly application server. Our application is first built by Angular CLI and the produced files are then packed by Maven into a single deployable WAR file. The problem is that when we try to build the application with Angular CLI for the second time, there is already an output in the Maven `target` folder and it tries to include the files inside this folder into the JS bundle. The build process eventually fails as it runs out of memory while trying to include the generated WAR file as a string.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./target/my-app.war
Module parse failed: Unterminated string constant (1:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| module.exports = "PK\u0003\u0004\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
...
```

In general, I have noticed that any file I put inside our project folder is picked up by `raw-loader` (used by Angular CLI) and added to the application bundle during the build process. So my question is: How can I make Angular CLI ignore such files?

We use Angular 5.2.10 and Angular CLI 1.7.4.

Comment: Apparently you can exclude files by adding the file path to the "exclude" section of your `.tsconfig`. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050 . Have you tried this?

Comment: @Zze Yes, I have tried it and it does not work.